# wordpress nav menu link text changin color after clicking

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme, twenty-ten-theme

I have a wordpress design using te twenty twelve theme. I have set the text of the main navigation tabs to a blue color. However when I click on these nav links, the text temporarily changes to black before loading the target page. I need them to stay blue the whole time (for designing purposes).

I have tried:

```
.main-navigation li, 
.main-navigation li a:hover, 
.main-navigation li a:visited, 
.main-navigation li a:active, etc etc etc{
     color:#58838f;
}
```

But no luck. Website is https://knows.online. Please click on the navigation links and then take out the mouse quickly before the next page load, the links turn to black, you will see what I mean.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: maybe you have forgotten `a:focus`? i see this rule that might apply when link is clicked, if not overriden by your rules: `.main-navigation li a:hover, .main-navigation li a:focus { color: #000; }` (style.css:1543)

Comment: @Kaddath YOU ARE THE MAN!!!! I have been struggling with this for hours XD Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you're welcome, always glad to help!